# Java Spring multiple ModelAttribute

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am creating a web application and have a question is it possible to write multiple ModelAttribute in Spring or not?

I tried something like this but I always get a 0. I also tried with spring binding but I get a 0 again. Thanks.

This is my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/assignguesttohotel",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView assignguesttohotel_form(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    return new ModelAndView("assignguesttohotel");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/assign",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView assigning(Guest guest, Hotel hotel) {
    ModelAndView m = new ModelAndView();
    System.out.println(guest.getId() + " " + hotel.getId());
    m.addObject("guestid", guest.getId());
    m.addObject("hotelid", hotel.getId());
    HotelDAO dao = new HotelDAO();
    dao.assignGuestToHotel(guest.getId(), hotel.getId());
    m.setViewName("temp");
    return m;
}
```

And the JSP (assignguesttohotel.jsp).

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Guest register</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <h1>Search Guest by name</h1>
    <form:form action="assign" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Guest id:</td>
                <td>
<%--                    <spring:bind path="guestid.id">--%>
<%--                        <input name="${status.expression}" type="number" value="${status.value}">--%>
<%--                    </spring:bind>--%>
                    <input name="guestid" type="number">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hotel id:</td>
                <td>
<%--                    <spring:bind path="hotelid.id">--%>
<%--                        <input name="${status.expression}" type="number" value="${status.value}">--%>
<%--                    </spring:bind>--%>
                    <input name="hotelid" type="number">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Seach"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use multiple Model Attributes to receive multiple objects in the controller and we can also send multiple objects to the view page.

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <div>
  <label>Leave a comment below</label>
  <textarea th:field="${rootComment.text}" rows="3"></textarea>
   </div>
<textarea th:field="${anotherObject.text}" rows="3"></textarea>
   </div>
  </form>



 Controller
    @PostMapping("/receive")
    String receiveObjects(Comment rootComment, Object2 anotherObject){
     ........
     }
```

I am using thymeleaf so I have mentioned "th" thymeleaf tags.